# Push Button (On/Off) in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On the Windows Form application I have a Lamp image (a black and white one, and a bright one. For OFF and ON respectively).

Using the Button how can I achieve the scenario such that same button will turn the property of the image (pictureBox in my case) to show the Lamp as ON and pressing the same button again will turn the Lamp off.

I am accessing the 'Visible' property of picture box.

Comment: You could use a check box.  This is the scenario they are designed for (toggling a boolean value).

Comment: Yes but I don't want to use the checkBox. I want to use and display the Button with the Text ON/OFF. Or do you mean that I display the Button which is behind the scene a checkBox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speed Button with Glyph or Similar in Visual Studio 2010 using WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467874/speed-button-with-glyph-or-similar-in-visual-studio-2010-using-winforms)

Comment: @Jasmine: There is an `Appearance` property on a check box that you can set to `Button`.  Or you could do what you're suggesting :)

Comment: Thanks I got two solution, one this and one from Anders as well. Oh and Hans, now get some more votes to close this. But do you want to? lolz

Comment: @Jasmine: The question and answer are duplicate, even if the title isn't (yes, the title of the other question sucks, but this one will point to that one if it ends up closed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put two images on top of each other and get the button to switch which one of them is enabled.

In the form designer you make one of them visible and the other non-visible. The code in the button handler can then be something like:

```
lightImage.Visible = !lightImage.Visible;
darkImage.Visible = != lightImage.Visible;
```

That will swap which one is visible and eliminate the need to keep state elsewhere.

Comment: I;m not sure about the way to put 2 images over each other, but if you want to reach the same effect: 
- place the 2 image files in your project resources
- in the click event of the button, toggle the button image depending on a setting:

Properties.Settings.Default.IsOptimizedForTracer = !Properties.Settings.Default.IsOptimizedForTracer;

if (!Properties.Settings.Default.IsOptimizedForTracer)
{
 btnOptimizeForTracer.Image = Properties.Resources.TracerOFF;
 return;
}

btnOptimizeForTracer.Image = Properties.Resources.TracerON;

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but you can use a checkbox and set the appearance to button.
I think that would do what is expected by the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the way to put 2 images over each other, but if you want to reach the same effect:

- place the 2 image files in your project resources
- in the click event of the button, toggle the button image depending on a setting:

this would be in the click event:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.IsOptimizedForTracer !=Properties.Settings.Default.IsOptimizedForTracer;

if (!Properties.Settings.Default.IsOptimizedForTracer)
{
btnOptimizeForTracer.Image = Properties.Resources.TracerOFF;
return;
}

btnOptimizeForTracer.Image = Properties.Resources.TracerON;
```